# Android clipboard.getText() is deprecated; how then to get the text item that's in it?

Tags: android, clipboard

This works fine, showing me exactly what was the last string put into Android clipboard, which happens to be `euswcnmst`.

`Log.w("clip", clipboard.getText().toString());`

But `getText` is deprecated for `clipboard` objects.

Meanwhile, if I do  `Log.w("clip", clipboard.getPrimaryClip().toString());`, I get this, exactly as shown
`ClipData { text/plain "label" {T:euswcnmst} }`

I see what I want, and, assuming this format is always used for string clipboard items, I can use `String` functions (find `:` and subsequent `}` and do `substring`) to extract `euswcnmst`, but that's a hack.

What SHOULD I do?

**EDIT**

Based on Commonsware's Answer, *here's* what I should do:

```
ClipData clip = clipboard.getPrimaryClip();

if(clip == null || clip.getItemCount() == 0)
  return; // ... whatever; just don't go to next line

String t = clip.getItemAt(0).getText().toString();
```

*EDIT 2*

If the last ITEM in the clipboard was NOT text, the above code gives this error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference`

Here's the fix (I added the third line below):

```
if(   clip == null 
   || clip.getItemCount() == 0 
   || clip.getItemCount() > 0 && clip.getItemAt(0).getText() == null
  )
    return; // ... whatever; just don't go to next line
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please understand that the clipboard is not purely for text. Complex constructs can be placed on the clipboard, in the form of 1 to N `ClipData.Item` objects inside the `ClipData` object that you are getting from `getPrimaryClip()`.

Given your `ClipData`, call `getItemCount()` to determine the number of items. For whichever item(s) you wish to attempt to use, call `getItemAt()` on the `ClipData` to get the corresponding `ClipData.Item`. On that item, you can call `getText()` or `coerceToText()` to try to get a text representation of that item.

Comment: I do understand that all manner of items can be put into the clipboard. Thank you. I got what I need.

Comment: @DSlomer64: Yes, that was a typo -- fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use below code

```
String copyString = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText()
```

Comment: That's a sure way to get a crash if the item at 0 is not a text.

Answer (score 0):

**Install the library, Clipboard has been deprecated and will be removed from React Native in the future.**

```
npm install --save @react-native-clipboard/clipboard

import Clipboard from '@react-native-clipboard/clipboard';

const [copiedText, setCopiedText] = useState('');

  const copyToClipboard = () => {
    Clipboard.setString('hello world');
  };

  const fetchCopiedText = async () => {
    const text = await Clipboard.getString();
    setCopiedText(text);
  };
```

Comment: Thank you. I assume it's not VBA code since I don't think VBA will allow all those Const statements and definitely not lambda expressions. And await' and 'async' look foreign to VBA ,too. In a few ways the code reminds me of Java, so because of that resemblance, I'm guessing the code is Kotlin (if not Java}, which I've never used. Looks concise and I'm sure enough that it'd work somewhere, but not for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clipData=ClipData.newPlainText("label",key.getText().toString());
            cm.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copied :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```