# Is There An Alternative For ClipboardManager.getText() (Which is depreciated)?

Tags: java, android

I would like to have my app check to see if the text in a text view has already been copied to the clipboard. The code that I have been using has been depreciated, and I hate using depreciated codes. My copy text to clipboard works though. Here is what I have so far...

```
    ClipboardManager cbm = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clip = ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copy", 
                                    tv.getText().toString());
    if (tv.getText().toString().equals(cbm.getText())){ //cbm.getText() is depreciated (Any suggestions on this part?)
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The text has already been copied to your clipboard!", 
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
       cbm.setPrimaryClip(clip);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text is copied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Do see the commonsware thoughts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196571/android-clipboard-gettext-is-deprecated-how-then-to-get-the-text-item-thats

Comment: Thanks notTdar that link helped a lot!

Comment: welcome buddy..